# Use Regex to detect the latest direct download link URL and thus quickly DL the latest software using AHK or other script lang

Tags: regex, google-chrome, url, download

I am attempting to use AutoHotkey to launch google chrome to a specific URL that will download the latest version of CCleaner.exe. Everytime a new version is released the version numbers change the URL. How can I open chrome and detect the current correct URL that will allow me to download the file. Currently I get an error because my URL is out of date and no loger representative of the latest release.

for my ahk script I have used this with success to open chrome to the url of my choosing. I just am not sure how to get it to auto detect the new URL of the next software version.

```
~d & ~c::
    If WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
        {
        Run, "chrome.exe" --new-tab "https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup559.exe", C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\, Max, chromePID
        WinWait, ahk_pid %chromePID%,, 1
        WinActivate, ahk_pid %chromePID%,, 1
        WinWaitActive, ahk_pid %chromePID%,, 1
        Return
              }
    Else {
        Run, chrome.exe --new-tab "https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup559.exe", C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\, Max, chromePID
        WinWait, ahk_pid %chromePID%,, 1
        WinWaitActive, "ahk_exe chrome.exe",, 1
        Return
              }
```

My current script will open the URL (https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup559.exe) that I listed in my code. However, it won't change to the latest URL that has the new version number for the latest software release and thus gives an error. The new URL could look like the following as an example (https://download.ccleaner.com/ccsetup601.exe) How can I open chrome to the general URL and auto detect the correct download link that has the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should go on the following link: https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard and look the download URL which has this pattern:

```
https:\/\/download.ccleaner.com\/ccsetup(\d*).exe
```

Following this documentation: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm

```
FoundPos := RegExMatch(yourURL, "https:\/\/download.ccleaner.com\/ccsetup(\d*).exe", VersionValue)
```

And then use `VersionValue`.

The `(\d*)` will catch the digits.

Comment: Great idea. I'll check that out now. Thanks for taking a second to help me out!

Comment: Npok, I am not sure how to use your solution. I thought I would figure it out and I have extensively researched regex on multiple websites but I am just stuck. what should i put in place of "yourURL" ? Also what did you mean by "And then use VersionValue? I really appreciate the help you've given. I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: By this sentence: "maybe you should go on the following link: https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard and look for the downloadable URL" I meant that you may be able to parse the HTML to catch the last version of CCleaner. It's not very fancy but a good quick-win